# Where are the other machine gun weight mods?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I found one weight mod for the machine guns. My question is where are the rest? I want to lighten my load of weapons and still pack a punch!

Comment: why in the world did i get downvoted.

Comment: I think there's someone voting just for kicks, every answer on this Q got downvoted as well

Comment: I wish there was a sniper rifle weight mod :3

Comment: @yx. When I first got the SMG mod I was like ">:D I will be the bringer of doom, running around with +200% recharge speed and a shotgun+AR+sniper" to say I was sad when I realised I wouldn't be reducing the weight of anything but SMG's is an understatement.

Answer (score 7):

There is only one weapon mod that lowers the weight of weapons, it's called "Ultralight Materials" and it's only available for SMG's.

It has 5 ranks, each decreasing the weight by an extra 10%, starting at 50%.

> Rank 1: 50%
>
> Rank 2: 60%
>
> Rank 3: 70%
>
> Rank 4: 80%
>
> Rank 5: 90%

Comment: Why did this get a downvote?